# Functional python programming and conditionals

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a python function in a functional way. The problem is I don't know, how to  transform an if conditional into a functional style. I have two variables: `A` and `C`, which I want to check for the following conditions:

```
def function():
    if(A==0): return 0
    elif(C!=0): return 0
    elif(A > 4): return 0
    else: someOtherFunction()
```

I looked at the [lambda shortcircuiting](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-prog/index.html), but I couldn't get it to work.

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Returning ``0`` to indicate failure is a really bad practice. I suggest you either throw an exception (preferable), or in a worst-case, return ``None``.

Comment: I'm probably the only one, but this question makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: The issue I have is that Python is **not** a pure functional language, so it shouldn't be used like one. Python has functional aspects, which is great for some tasks, but for tasks like this, the imperative style is far clearer and easier, so use it.

Comment: It's possible to do it in one line: "return 0 if A == 0 else (0 if C != 0 else (0 if A > 4 else someOtherFunction()))" with lack of readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [link you posted](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-prog/index.html):

> FP either discourages or outright disallows statements, 
>    and instead works with the evaluation of expressions

So instead of `if`-statements, you could use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
def function():
    return (0 if ((A == 0) or (C != 0) or (A > 4)) else
            someOtherFunction())
```

or, (especially useful if there were many *different* values):

```
def function():
    return (0 if A == 0 else
            0 if C != 0 else
            0 if A > 4 else
            someOtherFunction())
```

---

By the way, the linked article proposes

```
(<cond1> and func1()) or (<cond2> and func2()) or (func3())
```

as a short-curcuiting equivalent to

```
if <cond1>:   func1()
elif <cond2>: func2()
else:         func3()
```

The problem is they are not equivalent! The boolean expression fails to return the right value when `<cond1>` is Truish but `func1()` is Falsish (e.g. `False` or `0` or `None`). (Or similarly when `<cond2>` is Truish but `func2` is Falsish.)

```
(<cond1> and func1())
```

is written with the intention of evaluating to `func1()` when `<cond1>` is Truish, but when `func1()` is Falsish, `(<cond1> and func1())` evaluates to `False`, so the entire expression is passed over and Python goes on to evaluate `(<cond2> and func2())` instead of short-circuiting.

So here is a bit of interesting history. In 2005,
[Raymond Hettinger found](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056510.html) a similar hard-to-find bug in `type(z)==types.ComplexType and z.real or z` when `z = (0+4j)` because `z.real` is Falsish. Motivated by a desire to save us from similar bugs, the idea of using [a less error-prone syntax](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) (conditional expressions) was born.

Comment: The third code is what I was looking for, but it seems there is something syntactically wrong with that code...

Comment: I'm curious how to write that without the ternary, using only booleans (failed myself on that).

Comment: @thg435: You could perhaps use `(boolean and return_value)` expressions. For example: `(False and 'retvalA') or (True and 'retvalB') or 'retvalC'` evaluates to `'retvalB'`. You have to be careful that your return values are Truish, however. It was to surmount the problem of returning Falsish values that ternary expressions were created.

Comment: @unutbu: yes, but how this would look in this specific case (retval=0)?

Comment: @thg435: Sorry, I was editing my comment before I saw yours. I don't think you can do it with just boolean expressions.

Comment: @thg435: A bit of interesting history: [Raymond Hettinger found](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056546.html) `type(z)==types.ComplexType and z.real or z` contained a hard-to-find bug when `z = (0+4j)` because `z.real` is Falsish. Motivated by a desire to save us from similar bugs, [PEP308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) was born.

Comment: @unutbu: interesting indeed. I think it would be helpful to add your comments above to the answer, for the sake of future generations ))

Comment: @thg435: "Ternary expressions" are not something to be avoided in functional programming. if/then/else was very long ago seen to be useful as an **expression**, not a statement, in functional programming, and even enforced-purity languages like Haskell have it. In Haskell one normally prefers pattern matching to if/then/else (where applicable), but Python doesn't have pattern matching. `boolean and return_value` is a hack that is quite un-FP in spirit, because functional programmers would prefer to think of `and` as a simple binary function from boolean values to a boolean.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing non-"functional style" in your current code! who said conditionals are *not* functional anyway? Practically all functional languages have a conditional operator of some sort, for instance the `cond` special form in Lisp.

I'd take issue with the code if it were using the assignment operator, or mutating state in some way (say, appending to a list) but as it is, the function in the question is already in a "functional style" - there are no state changes.

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
return A != 0 and C == 0 and A <= 4 and someOtherFunction()
```

The above will return `False` if either `A == 0` or `C != 0` or `A > 4`, in all other cases it will return the value of calling `someOtherFunction()`. And by the way, `False` can be assumed to evaluate to `0` (for example, `42 + False == 42`), so the semantics in the code in the question will be preserved from the caller's point of view.

Notice that you're taking the information in the link out of context. There's absolutely no need to use a `lambda` for this, the article is only explaining how to get around an inherent limitation of `lambda`s in Python, which is that you can't return statements inside (like `if-elif-else`) - only expressions are allowed, but you can fake them with boolean operators. In the context of a normal *function* by all means, use conditionals.

Comment: I agree, but according to the link I provided in my first post, if-conditionals can be converted into lambda expressions. In my assignment it says I should make my code as functional-like as possible, that`s why I˙m asking.

Comment: Even if they _can_ be converted, by all means don't. You're taking things to the extreme, such a contrived code will get you nowhere. I'm certain that's not what your teacher has in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Although Peter Norvig is a really great guy, his website is pretty hard to search.

I remember reading about [Can I do the equivalent of (test ? result : alternative) in Python?](http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html) on his site a while back during some research before a functional Python talk.

I'm not going to sway you one way or the other in light of my findings, but you should still go and read the section about ternary conditional operators in a functional style.

```
def if_(test, result, alternative=None):
    "If test is true, 'do' result, else alternative. 'Do' means call if callable."
    if test:
        if callable(result): result = result()
        return result
    else:
        if callable(alternative): alternative = alternative()
        return alternative
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it as you have it.

Python does *not* have the syntax and library built-ins to make it easy to program all functions to directly return a single expression. That's not the most important part of functional style anyway, the most important part is making sure that your functions maintain **referential integrity**. Basically this means that whenever you supply them with the same input values they return the same output.

So when trying to program functionally in Python, I do *not* refrain from using statements entirely. I use a block of local variable assignments as an equivalent of `let ... in ...` from Haskell. I use an if/elif/else chain as an equivalent of a `case` expression from Haskell. And often there are built-in types which do not provide an adequate interface to create new "modified" versions of them rather than updating them in-place, so you instead have to implement such operations with an explicit copy operation and then using mutations on the new copy.

Python allows you to implement functional-style *designs* directly. You can easily structure your program as a whole bunch of functions which explicitly pass state around and don't have side effects, so you can design your high level *algorithms* in a very similar way that you would in a functional programming language. Nearly every programming language supports functional programming in this sense, if you're prepared to stomach the boilerplate necessary to fake first class functions. Since Python *has* first class functions, you don't even have to put up with boilerplate.

But that's as far as Python goes in supporting functional programming. It does't really support implementing functions as single referentially-transparent expressions. But that doesn't really matter. In a language that doesn't enforce or track purity, you get pretty much all the benefits of functional programming that you can by simply *designing* your program as a bunch of referentially transparent functions, and then how you implement those functions doesn't actually matter as long as the *interface* is kept referentially transparent.